# PHP MySQL multiple rows not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code for sending mails to users from DB,
but mail is always sent just to first user, even if changing order.
(request is sent from AJAX)

```
    $headers = ...

    $mailbody = ...

    $sql = 'SELECT `email`, `name` FROM `users`'; 
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
            }

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
            if (mail($row['email'],"title", $mailbody, $headers)) {
            echo 'mail '.$row['name'].' OK';
            return TRUE;
          } else {
            echo 'MAIL ERROR!!!';
            return FALSE;
          }
    }
```

Comment: You're returning from the function after you send the first mail.

Comment: did you print_r($rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you do `return TRUE` after the first successful mail. That ends the function. Take out that line, and put it after the `foreach` is done.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help! Worked!

Answer (score 0):

`return TRUE;` and `return FALSE;` stop the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this line: `return TRUE;`. It's causing your function/script to end right there, instead of continuing with the foreach loop.

If you want the script to stop on the first failure, this should work:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `email`, `name` FROM `users`'; 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
        }
foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if (mail($row['email'],"title", $mailbody, $headers)) {
        echo 'mail '.$row['name'].' OK';
      } else {
        echo 'MAIL ERROR!!!';
        return FALSE;
      }
}
return TRUE;
```

It will return true if all the emails have been sent sucessfully, otherwise it will return false on the first failure.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use return true or false the foreach loop stop remove it and try again or you can wrap it in a function and then if success return true (after the foreach loop) else return false